# Pidgin not present in 12.10 repositories, how do i get one?

Tags: repository, pidgin

I want to install Pidgin on my 12.10 clean install system. When I go to the `Software Center` and try to install the client I get an error saying:-

`Not found`
`There isn’t a software package called “pidgin” in your current software sources.`

Any ideas which repositories i need to import to get this done.

---

ERROR:-

```
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pidgin/pidgin-data_2.10.6-0ubuntu1_all.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/pidgin/pidgin_2.10.6-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.156 80]
```

Comment: @jokerdino, thanks you can add your comment as an answer so that i can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pidgin` is in the universe repository. Make sure you have the option to download and install packages from universe enabled.

Open software-center. Go to Edit menu --> Open software sources and check *Universe* option.

[image: software-sources-gtk]

After checking the option, run the following commands to install `pidgin`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect something may be wrong with the archive server.

Run `sudo software-properties-gtk` and select a different server/mirror, preferably the nearest one geographically.
Pidgin is most definitely in Quantal, and should be downloadable from [alternative servers](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/i386/pidgin/download).